# Selection of "best split" at a given node in RF

Tags: random-forest

At a given node, random forests sample `k` (aka `mtry`) variables (predictors). Then they pick the variable for which they get the best split.

How is this specifically determined? From what I understand RF do something like this:

```
for variable in variables_sampled:
 for threshold in possible_thresholds:
     check data purity (i.e. entropy) according to the divisions A and B where
      A: (variable > threshold) and B: (variable <= threshold)
```

Is this understanding correct? How are `possible_thresholds` chosen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible thresholds are every value of that variable observed in the data.  If instances are sorted by the value of that feature, the computation is actually pretty fast.  I think Breiman likes gini impurity rather than entropy as his split criterion.